# Appium, Cucumber and Junit how to run tests in parallel on multiple devices

Tags: java, selenium, junit, appium, parallel-testing

**Trying to execute my appium tests in parallel on multiple devices.**

I currently can execute my test cases on one android device. After a chopping and changing I cannot get my tests to run in parallel.

Heres my current set up. Hoping to execute tests in parallel without the need for saucelabs or selenium grid.

Example of my Junit runner

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.json", "pretty"}, features = {
    "src/test/resources/features/
},
    glue = "com.test.stepdefs")
public class RunCukesTest {

  private static AppiumDriverLocalService service;
  public static File file;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void startAppium() throws IOException {

    System.out.println("YOUR OS NAME : " + osName);

    String nodePath = null;
    String appiumPath = null;

    ServerArgument argument;

    if (osName.contains("mac")) {
//            mac paths
      nodePath = "/usr/local/bin/node";
      appiumPath = "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js";

      service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                                                          .usingDriverExecutable(new File(nodePath))
                                                          .usingPort(4723)
                                                          .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL,
                                                                        "error")                                                         
                                                          .withAppiumJS(new File(appiumPath)));
    } else if (osName.contains("windows")) {

      service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();

    } else if (osName.contains("linux")) {
//    linuxs path
      nodePath = System.getenv("PRODUCTION") + "/.linuxbrew/bin/node";
      appiumPath =
          System.getenv("PRODUCTION") + "/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js";
      service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                                                          .usingDriverExecutable(new File(nodePath))
                                                          .usingPort(4723)
                                                          .withAppiumJS(new File(appiumPath)));
    }

    service.addOutPutStream(stream);
    service.start();
  }

  @AfterClass
  public static void stopAppium() {
    service.stop();
  }
```

and an example of my

```
@Configuration
public class AppUtils {
    @Value("${explicit.wait}")
    public int explicitWaitTime;
    @Value("${implicit.wait}")
    public int implicitWaitTime;
    @Value("${default.wait}")
    public int defaultWaitTime;
    public String applicationName;
    public DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
    @Value("${appium.server.port}")
    private String appiumPort;
    @Value("${automation.instrumentation}")
    private String instrumentation;
    @Value("${browser.name}")
    private String browserName;
    @Value("${platform.name}")
    private String platformName;
    @Value("${device.name}")
    private String deviceName;
    @Value("${platform.version}")
    private String platformVersion;
    @Value("${new.command.timeout}")
    private String newCommandTimeout;
    @Value("${app.package}")
    private String appPackage;
    @Value("${device.ready.timeout}")
    private String deviceReadyTimeout;
    private URL serverUrl;
    private AppiumDriver<? extends MobileElement> driver;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "quit")
    @Scope("cucumber-glue")
    public AndroidDriver getDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, platformVersion);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, platformName);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, deviceName);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, instrumentation);
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome"); //To be moved to properties
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main"); //To be moved to properties
        serverUrl = new URL("http://localhost:" + appiumPort + "/wd/hub");
//        LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
//        logPrefs.addPreferences()
//        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs);
        driver = new AndroidDriver(serverUrl, capabilities);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(implicitWaitTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.setLogLevel(Level.OFF);
        return (AndroidDriver) driver;
    }
}
```

Cannot find any good documentation on this and would appreciated any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should start another appium server instance listening on different port and then launch tests with this new server port capability.